# CRM Unable to get property 'refreshRibbon' of undefined or null reference

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

When calling `Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true)` from a web resource, I get this error:

> Unable to get property 'refreshRibbon' of undefined or null reference

in the `JSProvider.ashx` refreshRibbon, from firing an `onchange` event for an Attribute.

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting bug/feature with the onChange event:

```js
function onLoad() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_att").addOnChange(onChange); // OK!
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_att2").addOnChange(Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon);  // No Worky!
}
```

Any calls to Xrm, should be wrapped in another function, or an anonymous method.  No passing in the function directly.

```
function onChange() {
    Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon();
}
```

Comment: wow ok, any idea why this is happening? To me there seems very little difference

Comment: @jasonscript yes, the "No Worky" version is pointing to a specific Xrm instance.  The second one is pointing to whatever window.Xrm is, so if Microsoft creates a new Xrm instance, it will get it.